# R: How to use dplyr with changing date ranges

Tags: r, date, range, grouping

extremely new to R here.

Imagine I have a df with three columns: Article title, Year published (1968-2019), author

```
Title Year Author
title1 1968 John
title2 1968 Mary
title3 1968 John
title4 1968 Eric
title5 1969 Matthew
title6 1969 Eric
title7 1970 Sara
title8 1970 John
...
title99 2019 Mike
title100 2019 Ian
```

I want to determine the proportion of articles published each year by authors who have not published in the previous five years (i.e., what proportion of authors who published in 2019 did not publish in 2018,2017,2016,2015,2014). I would like to report this proportion for every year (e.g., 2018 would reflect proportion of authors who hadn't published anything in 2017,2016,2015,2014,2013).

I'm getting hung up on how to set the year range such that it captures data from the preceding five years without having to set each new range manually. Any pointers would be very welcome for this newbie!

Comment: You'd have to loop over each row and look back 5 years from the current year I believe. In SQL or the *data.table* package, you could use a join on a range (non-equi join) - `a.year<b.year & a.year>=(b.year-5)` or similar, which would probably simplify the logic.

Comment: I "second" @thelatemail's suggestion that SQL and `data.table` have non-equi join logic; while `dplyr` is good in many ways, until it does this type of join, it is in my opinion not the best tool for this type of data manipulation.

Comment: And it has been in discussion for years, most recently with [tidyverse/dplyr#2240](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2240). (On researching this, I really like @krlmlr's suggestion for `left_join(..., join_by(FundID == FundID, yearmonth > gmonth + 3, yearmonth <= gmonth + 15))`.) Unfortunately, that issue does not seem to have received many comments other than "me too".